# How to make the countdown to every Sunday in the month?

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter, countdown

I have a countdown on my site, I want it to countdown to next Sunday at 11:00 A.M, and when its sunday 11:01 A.M I want it to automatically countdown to the next Sunday at 11:00 A.M. and I want that to repeat every month..

I have this script, but cant seem to get it to work, can some one help me here ?

Thanks in advance

here is my html...

```
<div class="eventtd">
        <div class="nextevt">Next Service Start In:</div>
           <div class="time" contents="2" rel="1374397200">
       </div> <!-- end time -->
```

and here's the script I use, as of right now when it reach 0 it continue on into negative values instead of reseting.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

if (timerhelp == 'yes') {
    var init = setInterval(animation, 100);
}
function animation(){       
    var deadline1 = $('.time').attr('rel');
    var deadline2 = $('.time').attr('contents');
    var now = new Date();
    now = Math.floor(now / 1000);
    now = now + Math.floor(deadline2 * 60 * 60);
    var counter1 = deadline1 - now;
    var seconds1=Math.floor(counter1 % 60);
    if (seconds1 < 10 && seconds1 > 0 ){
        seconds1 = '0'+seconds1;

    }
    counter1=counter1/60;
    var minutes1=Math.floor(counter1 % 60);
    if (minutes1 < 10 && minutes1 > 0){
        minutes1 = '0'+minutes1;

    }
    counter1=counter1/60;
    var hours1=Math.floor(counter1 % 24);
    if (hours1 < 10 && hours1 > 0){
        hours1 = '0'+hours1;
    }
    counter1=counter1/24;
    var days1=Math.floor(counter1);
    if (days1 < 10 && days1 > 0){
        days1 = '0'+days1;
    }
    $('.time').html('<table><tbody><tr><th class="day">'+days1+'</th><th class="day">'+hours1+'</th><th class="day">'+minutes1+'</th><th class="day">'+seconds1+'</th></tr><tr><th>Days</th><th>Hours</th><th>Min</th><th>Sec</th></tr></tbody></table>');


}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this:

```
var timerhelp = 'yes';
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

     nextSunday();

if (timerhelp == 'yes') {
    var init = setInterval(animation, 900); // did change to 900, no need to calculate it more than once a second :)
}
function animation(){       
    var deadline1 = $('.time').attr('rel');
    var deadline2 = $('.time').attr('contents');
    var now = new Date();
    now = Math.floor(now / 1000);
    now = now + Math.floor(deadline2 * 60 * 60);
    var counter1 = deadline1 - now;
    var seconds1=Math.floor(counter1 % 60);
    if (seconds1 < 10 && seconds1 > 0 ){
        seconds1 = '0'+seconds1;

    }
    counter1=counter1/60;
    var minutes1=Math.floor(counter1 % 60);
    if (minutes1 < 10 && minutes1 > 0){
        minutes1 = '0'+minutes1;

    }
    counter1=counter1/60;
    var hours1=Math.floor(counter1 % 24);
    if (hours1 < 10 && hours1 > 0){
        hours1 = '0'+hours1;
    }
    counter1=counter1/24;
    var days1=Math.floor(counter1);
    if (days1 < 10 && days1 > 0){
        days1 = '0'+days1;
    }
  if(days1<0&&hours1<0&&minutes1<0&&seconds1<0){
 nextSunday();
}
    $('.time').html('<table><tbody><tr><th class="day">'+days1+'</th><th class="day">'+hours1+'</th><th class="day">'+minutes1+'</th><th class="day">'+seconds1+'</th></tr><tr><th>Days</th><th>Hours</th><th>Min</th><th>Sec</th></tr></tbody></table>');


}
});

function nextSunday(){ 
var now = new Date().getTime() / 1000; // time in seconds;
var rel = $('.time').attr('rel');
    if(parseInt(now)>parseInt(rel)){
        var n = parseInt(rel)
        while(n<parseInt(now)){
            n =  n+604800;
        }
        $('.time').attr('rel',n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to do, still getting negative values.

Comment: the problem seems to be in `var counter1 = deadline1 - now;` use my answer to change deadline1 value.

Comment: please use Amadan's solution, it's beautiful.

Comment: Tried it, but still negative value.

Comment: see this please: http://jsfiddle.net/2PxsA/2/ You would still need to make changes.

Comment: Thanks, you suggested that I would still need to make changes what type of changes, I am still learning JS, I'm sure you can tell by now.

Comment: Thank you, so much, Now I hope I'm not over extending my welcome, but would that countdown reset every sunday at 11:01 A.M. because it's for a church and I was trying to have it reset every sunday, to let people know when the next service is going to be. Thanks

Comment: please see my answer once more it's full code with upgrade for the case when client would be online the timer goes to 0 point :) I made `nextSunday()` function

Comment: yes this would reset for every sunday. :) Please accept my answer :) P.S. you could test it by changing the date on your pc.

Comment: Glad I could help. if you need more help with the website email me : choi.al17@gmail.com, I'm new to javascript too, but together is always better :)

Comment: will do. I'm actually getting a flickering effect on reload, its that normal?

Comment: Sorry for late reply I was going home off work. Could email me instead of posting here? :)

Comment: It's okay had to drop a friend at the airport I literally just walked in. I emailed you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code should always give you the next Sunday:

```
var now = new Date();
var sunday = new Date();
sunday.setDate(now.getDate() - now.getDay()); // Make Sunday
sunday.setHours(11); // Set 11am
sunday.setMinutes(0);
sunday.setSeconds(0);
sunday.setMilliseconds(0);
if (sunday < now) sunday.setDate(sunday.getDate() + 7); // Make sure it's future
millisecondsLeft = sunday - now;
```

You can just check at each pass if `sunday < now`, and recalculate `sunday` if it is.

(If anyone is wondering, The "make sure it's future" line should trigger if you calculate `sunday` on Sunday afternoon...)

Comment: logically your code makes, perfect sense, but I can't seem to get it to work, i must be doing something wrong.